# Writing form to a text file PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new here.

Anyway, I'm working on an application system that logs your answers to the form into a text file called data.txt It was working for a while and then I tinkered with some stuff and it's not working anymore.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="unselectable">PvPCity Application</h1>
    <form target=_blank action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="IGN" placeholder="IGN" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Discord" placeholder="Discord" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age" autocomplete="off">
      <textarea name="Why" placeholder="Why do you want to be staff?" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
      <input onclick="window.location.href = 'http://pvpcity.dx.am/submitted/index.html';" type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
if( isset($_POST['IGN'] ) && isset( $_POST['Discord'] ) && isset( $_POST['Age'] ) && isset( $_POST['Why'] ) )
{
  $txt='  ##### IGN: '.$_POST['IGN'].'  ##### Discord: '.$_POST['Discord'].'  ##### Age: '.$_POST['Age'].'  ##### Why: '.$_POST['Why'] . PHP_EOL;
  file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Here is the code.
If you could tell me what is wrong that would be great.
The code here is from index.php
The submit button redirects to a different page when you click.
I honestly have no idea why it's not working

Comment: why do you do this? `onclick="window.location.href = 'http://pvpcity.dx.am/submitted/index.html';"`

Comment: and is that code from index.php?

Comment: to redirect them to a different page when they submit

Comment: yes it is from index.php

Comment: When I try this code it's working fine....

Comment: it says it in data,txt?

Comment: Yes I created data.txt file and i run the above code it's working

Comment: try making another file that it redirects to, that might be my problem. because thats what i tinkered with

Comment: So you want to submit the data in same page and redirect to another website right?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="unselectable">PvPCity Application</h1>
    <form target=_blank action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="IGN" placeholder="IGN" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Discord" placeholder="Discord" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age" autocomplete="off">
      <textarea name="Why" placeholder="Why do you want to be staff?" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
if( isset($_POST['IGN'] ) && isset( $_POST['Discord'] ) && isset( $_POST['Age'] ) && isset( $_POST['Why'] ) )
{
  $txt='  ##### IGN: '.$_POST['IGN'].'  ##### Discord: '.$_POST['Discord'].'  ##### Age: '.$_POST['Age'].'  ##### Why: '.$_POST['Why'] . PHP_EOL;
  if(file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND)){
     header('Location: http://pvpcity.dx.am/submitted/index.html');
 }else{
  echo 'data is not saved';
 }
}
?>
```

I did some alteration in that above code for redirect to another website. You don't want to redirect on click, you can do that via PHP header().

```
header('Location: http://pvpcity.dx.am/submitted/index.html');
```

This will redirect after submit the form...

Answer (score 1):

You should allow PHP to perform the redirection rather than allow people to potentially spoof others from your site. That said - you can simplify the collection of POSTed data a little by processing the POST array. The form will submit OK and redirect but the remote site will perhaps inaccurately report back that the application has been submitted  - presumably this will be hosted on that site also so not necessarily an issue.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $payload=array();
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value )$payload[]=sprintf('##### %s %s', $field, $value );
        file_put_contents( 'data.txt', implode( ' ',$payload ).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );

        header('Location: http://pvpcity.dx.am/submitted/index.html');
    }

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="unselectable">PvPCity Application</h1>
    <form target=_blank method="post">
      <input type="text" name="IGN" placeholder="IGN" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Discord" placeholder="Discord" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age" autocomplete="off">
      <textarea name="Why" placeholder="Why do you want to be staff?" autocomplete="off"></textarea>


      <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ram, just to clarify your code a little, is this creating an associative array ($payload) storing the $field name as the key and the $value as the value?

Comment: it's a regular array  of strings ( using `sprintf` for convenience ) which is compacted to a single string using `implode`. The benefit being here, to my mind, is that should you need to add fields to your form they will be recorded to this text file with no additional work

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I just hadn't seen that before as I'm newer to using PHP! Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need  `onclick="window.location.href = ...`  Your submission can go to same file (index.php), you just need a better condition and since your inputs are not marked as required you might use something like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $txt = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $txt = $txt. " ##### ".$key.': '.$value;
    }
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```